# AWS CloudWatch Dimension Value Contains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch, elastic-load-balancer

Assume my `LoadBalancer` name is app/test123/123abc where `123abc` is a unique ID. This is the end of the load balancer ARN.

I am currently retrieving the Cloudwatch stats by doing this:

```
GetMetricStatisticsRequest oRequest = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withStartTime(startTime)
            .withNamespace("AWS/ApplicationELB")
            .withPeriod(oneHour)
            .withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("LoadBalancer").withValue("app/test123/123abc"))
            .withMetricName("HTTPCode_Backend_2XX")
            .withStatistics("Sum")
            .withEndTime(endTime);
```

What I actually need is a `contains` rule... because I want to look up my load balancer based on `test123` and thus not include the unique part of the URL.

Is this possible?

Something like....

```
GetMetricStatisticsRequest oRequest = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withStartTime(startTime)
            .withNamespace("AWS/ApplicationELB")
            .withPeriod(oneHour)
            .withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("LoadBalancer").withValue.contains("test123"))
            .withMetricName("HTTPCode_Backend_2XX")
            .withStatistics("Sum")
            .withEndTime(endTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way of doing this. One workaround that I can think of:

- Get a list of all ELBs in your account using the [DescribeLoadBalancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLoadBalancers.html) API.

  - Since response is paginated, you might have to make multiple calls depending on how many ELBs you have.
  - The corresponding CLI command can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-load-balancers.html).
- From the returned [LoadBalancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_LoadBalancer.html)s, filter out the required one using the `LoadBalancerArn` field. You can use regex or simple String manipulation to achieve this.
- Call `GetMetricStatisticsRequest` as originally mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Search through the `listMetrics` and find the one your need then use it as a `.withDimensions(oDim)` filter.

```
List<Metric> oMetricList = new ArrayList<Metric>();
try
{
    oMetricList = client.listMetrics().getMetrics();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return null;
}

for (Metric oMetric : oMetricList)
{
    for (Dimension oDim : oMetric.getDimensions())
    {
        if (oDim.getName().contains(dimensionName) && oDimsgetValue().contains(lbName))
        {
           return oDim; 
        }
    }
}
```